# «Vè» è lo stesso di «ve’»?

Tags: word-meaning, apocope, interjections

Nel racconto *La Luna come un fungo* di Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Sentivo le grida dei compagni che salivano dal
>   mare: stavano passandosi la voce, indicandomi, facendomi le beffe, e le loro parole
>   sembrava mi giungessero da un altro mondo: - *Vè* Qfwfq lì, ah ah!

Ho cercato il vocabolo «vè» in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Tuttavia, nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ve/) ho trovato questa definizione:

> **ve’** ‹*vé*› interiez. – *Troncamento* di *vedi*, imperativo del v. vedere, col sign. di «guarda!»: *ve’ che non par che luca Lo raggio da sinistra a quel di sotto* (Dante). Frequente in usi region. come esclam. (anche nella grafia *veh* ), col sign. di «bada!», per rafforzare espressioni di avvertimento, di ammonizione e di minaccia: *attento, ve’, che cadi!; bada, ve’, che me la paghi!; non ci provare, ve’!* Anche rafforzativo, talora, di sì e no, a cui aggiunge una particolare sfumatura: *sì ve’; io no, ve’*. Più raram. con funzione più tenue, quasi a sottolineare le parole che precedono: *era buono, ve’, il vino; scusate, ve’; aspetta, ve’*.

La mia domanda è: quel «vè» che appare nel brano di Calvino è lo stesso di «ve’»? Si tratta, come spiegato dal Treccani, del troncamento dell'imperativo del verbo vedere con il significato di «guarda!»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso che in questo caso vè sia da intendere come una forma dialettale o colloquiale di ve', dato che si tratta di pescatori che si fanno beffe di un vecchio compagno che è rimasto insabbiato con la sua barca in un mondo senza spiagge.

Spesso nei discorsi diretti si trovano espressioni popolari che non sono perfette dal punto di vista grammaticale, e sottolineano il contensto non formale in cui sono formulate.

Comunque penso proprio che il senso sia «guarda lì Qfwfq! ha ha!» detto in modo colorito.